# Mesh "sticking" to vertices

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

[image]

When I add a subsurf modifier the mesh "sticks" to some of my vertices as if there was a double or mean crease add to it, but I'm very confident there isnt either. This has been happening alot recently and is very annoying. If anyone has any ideas I would appreicate it. 
P.S-  sometimes deleting the vertices then recreating it fixes the problem and sometimes it doesn't either way it time consuming and not ideal

Answer (score 2):

The normals were flipped the wrong way.

Comment: Congratulation  :) so probably you can also mark your answer as correct clicking on check icon under vote arrow as well. It lets others to know the Q was answered, visible from Q list too. Thanks